# Eclipse Jbehave eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, jbehave-plugin, jbehave-maven-plugin

I get this error when i try to open story file in eclipse kepler "Plug-in "org.jbehave.eclipse" was unable to instantiate class "org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.story.StoryEditor"."??

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.jbehave.eclipse" was unable to instantiate class "org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.story.StoryEditor".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2967)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenFileAction.openFile(OpenFileAction.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenSystemEditorAction.run(OpenSystemEditorAction.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.OpenActionGroup.runDefaultAction(OpenActionGroup.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.MainActionGroup.runDefaultAction(MainActionGroup.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator.handleOpen(ResourceNavigator.java:787)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator$6.open(ResourceNavigator.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.text.style.TextStyle.getPath(TextStyle.java:69)
    at org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.text.style.TextStylePreferences.load(TextStylePreferences.java:23)
    at org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.text.style.TextStylePreferences.getTheme(TextStylePreferences.java:117)
    at org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.story.StoryEditor.getTheme(StoryEditor.java:125)
    at org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.story.StoryEditor.<init>(StoryEditor.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 108 more
```

Comment: Is there a more detailed message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: I get this things: at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)

 at

Comment: Edit the question to add the log details

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils`  suggests that it is missing a plugin for org.apache.commons.lang

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second message in the stack is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
```

which means you're missing `commons-lang-*.jar` (where `*` is a version number). I just checked my Eclipse installation and there is no official JAR in my plugins folder. I've found it inside of a couple of plugins (in the `lib/` folder) where it's hidden from other plugins.

Try this:

1. Go to http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/ and find the latest build ("drop")
2. On the info page for the latest build, search for `commons.lang`
3. In my case, the last version of `org.apache.commons.lang` is 2.6.0.
   Note: `org.apache.commons.lang3` isn't compatible!!
4. Download the JAR
5. Put it into the folder `dropins/`
6. Restart Eclipse

If that doesn't work, reinstall the JBehave plugin.

Related:

- http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html